# Scala accessing members of runtime types using reflection of a class that extends a trait

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

Suppose I have a `MyItem` trait and its companion object has an `apply()` function that creates a class instance called `SubItem` that extends from `MyItem`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

trait MyItem {
  import MyItem._
  def num: Option[Int]
}

object MyItem {
  class SubItem(val num: Option[Int]) extends MyItem 

  def apply(num: Option[Int]): MyItem = new SubItem(num) // creates SubItem
}

def getTypeTag[T: ru.TypeTag](obj: T) = ru.typeTag[T]

val modifiedItem = MyItem(Some(11))
val theType = getTypeTag(modifiedItem).tpe
```

If you print out `theType` above, it will be `MyItem`.

At this point if you try to use [reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) to modify the field `num`, it's not going to work because `MyItem` has `num` as a *method*, not a field (as in `MyItem.SubItem`):

```
val m = ru.runtimeMirror(modifiedItem.getClass.getClassLoader)
val numTermSymb = theType.decl(ru.TermName("num")).asTerm
val im = m.reflect(modifiedItem)
val numFieldMirror = im.reflectField(numTermSymb)  // not going to work
numFieldMirror.get
numFieldMirror.set(Some(999))  // my goal, if possible
```

Unfortunately, above will throw out `scala.ScalaReflectionException: expected a field or an accessor method symbol, you provided method num`.

Instead you should do the following:

```
val numTermSymb = theType.decl(ru.TermName("num")).asMethod
val im = m.reflect(modifiedItem)
val numFieldMirror = im.reflectMethod(numTermSymb)
numFieldMirror() // returns `Some(11)`
```

But my goal is to **access the SubItem class that extends MyItem and modify its field**. How can I get an instance of the type `MyItem` and modify the field in `MyItem.SubItem` that `MyItem`'s method `num` is accessing?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? _runtime_ **reflection** is discouraged for a number of reasons. Are you completely sure that your meta-problem can only be solved using **reflection**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I would personally avoid using reflection as much as I can. but this approach is what the senior engineer in my team is pushing for right now

Comment: That is sad to hear, I am pretty sure someone will come and provide a good answer to this problem but still, I would encourage you to open another question describing the meta-problem, it may help you to convince that _"senior"_ about a different approach, or at least it would help you in the future to be a better developer.

Comment: Thank you, I'll explore more and tell him what I think about this whole thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
val theType = getTypeTag(modifiedItem).tpe
```

with

```
val theType = ru.typeOf[MyItem.SubItem]
```

if you know the name of class statically or with

```
val theType = m.staticClass("pckg.MyItem.SubItem").typeSignature
```

if you know the name of class dynamically.

---

Try

```
val className = modifiedItem.getClass.getName.replace('$', '.')
val theType = m.staticClass(className).typeSignature
```

---

Actually, `m.staticClass(className).typeSignature` is `AnyRef with pckg.MyItem {...}` i.e. parents/decls of `SubItem`

```
theType =:= ru.typeOf[MyItem.SubItem] // false
```

so, although `numFieldMirror.get/set` work, it's better to use `toType` instead of `typeSignature`

```
val className = modifiedItem.getClass.getName.replace('$', '.')
val theType = m.staticClass(className).toType

theType =:= ru.typeOf[MyItem.SubItem] // true
```

---

One more way is purely Scala-like

```
val instanceMirror = m.reflect(modifiedItem) 
val theType = instanceMirror.symbol.toType

theType =:= ru.typeOf[MyItem.SubItem] // true
```

It's even better because doesn't use error-prone and implementation-dependent operations on strings (`replace`).

Comment: Except I cannot do that. :( I simplified the code there, but the actual function that takes `modifiedItem` is of generic type `T`, and we need to find out the type at runtime using reflection e.g.
```def myFunc[T:ClassTag](modifiedItem: T)(implicit tag:ru.TypeTag[T]): T = {
  val theType = getTypeTag(modifiedItem).tpe
  // blah blah do the rest here
}```

Comment: @Hush See update with `staticClass`. If you still can't do that then you should edit your question providing a minimal code corresponding your actual use case.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Hush Actually, it's better to use `toType` instead of `typeSignature`. See update.

Comment: @Hush One more way is `val instanceMirror = m.reflect(modifiedItem)` `val theType = instanceMirror.symbol.toType`. It's better because doesn't use operations on strings (`replace`).